# Mako escaping issue within Pyramid

Tags: python, escaping, pyramid, mako

I need to put javascript function to mako template. The first argument of this function is string, so I write in my *.mako file (dict(field_name='geom')):

```
init_map(
    '${field_name}'
);
```

But when I see my html page it loks like:

```
init_map(
    &#39;geom&#39;
)
```

How I can disable escaping in this case?

Rendering performs the following way:

```
from pyramid.renderers import render
render('georenderer/map.mako', template_args)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to include the quotes in your expression I think. You can use the `json` module to output valid JavaScript literals:

```
dict(field_name=json.dumps('geom'))
```

and in your template:

```
init_map(
    ${field_name | n}
);
```

The quotes are then generated by the `.dumps()` function, and the `| n` filter ensures they are not escaped; you've already made your values JavaScript safe, you don't need them HTML-safe either.

The added advantage is that the module will escape any quotes in your JavaScript values as well, and handle unicode properly:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(u'Quotes and unicode: " \u00d8')
"Quotes and unicode: \" \u00d8"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in my case problem probably was connected with nested mako templates. When I've built one template without nested all become work fine.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters Don't forget about quotes `'${field_name | n}'`... :)

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: No! The quotes are provided by the json.dumps module!

Answer (score 1):

Try `n` filter. According to [the docs](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html#turning-off-filtering-with-the-n-filter), it disables escaping (or any other default filtering):

```
${field_name | n}
```

UPDATE: Sorry I didn't notice that the quotes are *around* the expression. And now it seem very strange...

Comment: The problem is that the quotes *around* the expression are escaped.

Comment: So exactly and it looks like Pyramid issue, because directly rendreing through Mako works fine.